# ssh client and cannot connect to X server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, x-server, ssh-agent

my computer is Windows (Ubuntu), the host is Linux. I am trying to access a visualization program on the host computer (Linux) in my office from my home laptop (Windows) via ssh client and when trying to access the program, I get the following message: cannot connect to X server

I am accessing the host computer using ssh -X -l [username] [host]

I'm not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: Is "cannot connect to X server" the entire error message?

Comment: Does "Windows (Ubuntu)" mean Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), or are you running a desktop version of Ubuntu inside a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Is X11 forwarding enabled in your settings? Try this :

```
ssh -Y -l username hostname
```

Comment: ssh -Y -l username hostname does not work!

Comment: I'm not sure about the X11--
I tried following the instructions in https://www.wikihow.com/Configure-X11-in-Linux to configure X11 and I could not get past step 4.